# Matrix operation name for element wise multiplication followed by addition

Tags: matrices

On [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/blurring_an_image) page, the following matrix operation is performed:

[image]

It looks like a Hadamard product followed by a dot product similar addition of all elements so the result is a 1x1 "matrix" (or a scalar?) of value 0.5.

Is there a name for this operation?

Comment: As indicated in the article to which you have linked, it is a convolution.

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11172

Comment: [See this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution)